# Using integrated authentication with EWS (exchange web services)

Tags: .net, iis, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm in the process of setting up a company intranet. One of the requests is to do some intregration with Exchange Server 2007.

In my tests I can authenticate to EWS just fine using NetworkCredential, as long as I'm passing in my username and password. In our intranet, I'd like to pass on the credientials of the logged in user. We'll be using windows integrated authentication only.

I can't seem to get this working - setting the credentials in the ExchangeServiceBinding to CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials didn't work.

.net and IIS 6 from the web server
Exchange 2007 on Windows 2003 server

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You have a better chance of getting an answer to this on server fault

Comment: Thanks, got the answer I was looking for on server fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer on serverfault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/73508/using-integrated-authentication-with-ews-exchange-web-services